# How to set query Limit on GTLQuery?

Tags: google-app-engine, swift2

This is my query that will return all of my users in the datastore:

```
    func getAllUsers(){
    let query = GTLQueryUser.queryForUserList()

    service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: {(ticket, response, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }
        else{
            let userCollection = response as! GTLUserCollection
            if let newUsers = userCollection.items() as? [GTLUserUser]{
                users = newUsers
                print("These are the users that are in data store")
                for user in users{
                    print (user.firstName)
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

How do I set the query limit to one so that I can only query one user at a time?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify in the query fields in your age that you can even enter a limit. Like so:

```
 @User.query_method(path="user/list", http_method="GET", name="user.list", query_fields=("limit", "user_bucket", "age","gender", "order", "pageToken"))
```

Then you generate client code with Google's discovery generated then you can go into the swift app and type:

```
query.limit = 1
```